# Why doesn't this cause circular import

Tags: python, import, flask

I have a flask app.

app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

from views import *

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

views.py

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Homepage"
```

So, here `app.py` is importing everything form `views.py` and views need `app` which is defined in `app.py`. But still its not causing circular import. Why?

I run this application using:

```
python app.py
```

Comment: It's because `app` is defined before you import `views`. If you swap the order of the first two lines in `app.py` it will fail.

Answer (score 4):

This looks similar to the [Larger Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/) document which Flask allows you to do when creating apps.

From the docs:

> ### Circular Imports
>
> Every Python programmer hates them, and yet we just added some: circular imports (That’s when two modules depend on each other. In this case `views.py` depends on `__init__.py`). Be advised that this is a bad idea in general but here it is actually fine. The reason for this is that we are not actually using the views in `__init__.py` and just ensuring the module is imported and we are doing that at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If we try to follow what the program does, it is something like that:

```
app = Flask(__name__) # OK
from views import * # Goes into views.py

from app import app # Looks into app.py, finds it, import it

# Defines home
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Homepage"

# import home and app, overriding app in app.py
# But views.app is the same as app.app, so it is still
# the same object

# Run main
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

I bet it computes something like that. Since app is defined before being imported, it's ok.

Comment: When in `views.py`, it does `from app import app`, it looks into `app.py`. In that case again `from views import *` should run from inside `app.py` and it should cause circular import?

Comment: I don't think so since it can find `app` and stop searching before seing again the actual `import` statement.